# ML_Net It says 'Features' is there but it doesn't exist

Tags: c#, ml.net

```
 public class TextData
{
    [LoadColumn(0)]
    public string Subject { get; set; }

    [LoadColumn(1), ColumnName("Valid")]
    public bool Valid { get; set; }

    [LoadColumn(2)]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

public class Prediction_Subejct : TextData
{
    [ColumnName("PredictedLabel")]
    public bool Prediction { get; set; }

    public float Probability { get; set; }

    public float Score;

    [ColumnName("PredictedSub")]
    public string SubFeatures { get; set; }
}
```

The code above is the class I created.

```
static IEstimator<ITransformer> Subject_ProcessData()
    {
        var subjectModel = _mlContext.Transforms.Conversion.MapValueToKey(inputColumnName: "Subject", outputColumnName: "Labels")
           .Append(_mlContext.Transforms.Text.FeaturizeText(inputColumnName: "Text", outputColumnName: "TextFeaturized"))
           .Append(_mlContext.BinaryClassification.Trainers.SdcaLogisticRegression(labelColumnName: "Valid", featureColumnName: "Features"))
           // Features 에 데이터를 연결
           .Append(_mlContext.Transforms.Concatenate("Features", "TextFeaturized"))
           
           // DataView 캐쉬
           .AppendCacheCheckpoint(_mlContext);

        return subjectModel;
    }
```

The code above is the pipeline I created.

```
 var Pipeline = pipeline.Append(_mlContext.MulticlassClassification.Trainers.SdcaMaximumEntropy("Label", "Features"))
        .Append(_mlContext.Transforms.Conversion.MapKeyToValue("PredictedLabel"));

        var model = Pipeline.Fit(_trainingDataView);
```

Running Fit() gave an error.

> Unhandled exception. System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Could not find feature column 'Features' (Parameter 'inputSchema')

**Why does it say 'Features' doesn't exist?**

Comment: https://github.com/using1047/ML.NET_NER_TEST.git

Comment: Maybe try putting the `Concatenate` before the `SdcaLogisticRegression` trainer and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

"Features" is reserved in the Concatenate method, it expects an array of features after it. So you will need to change this name.

Do something like:

```
var subjectModel=_mlContext.Transforms.Conversion.MapValueToKey(inputColumnName: "Subject", outputColumnName: "Labels")
   .Append(_mlContext.Transforms.Text.FeaturizeText(inputColumnName: "Text", outputColumnName: "TextFeaturized"))
.Append(_mlContext.Concatenate("Features", new[] {"TextFeaturized"})
```